# Removing empty spaces when the delegate is not visible in a gridview

Tags: gridview, qml

I am trying to use the following model and delegate components in a grid view. The model has a boolean role vis which turns the visible property of the delegate on or off. Later on I intend to bind this vis property to my backend.In this example the green button does not show up as intended but leaves an empty space between red and brown buttons. How do I get rid of the empty space. I just want the brown button to be next to red button

This is my model component

```
ListModel { 
    ListElement {
        rectcolor:"red"
        vis:true
    }
    ListElement {
        rectcolor:"green"
        vis:false
    }
    ListElement
    {rectcolor:"brown"
     vis:true
    }
}
```

This is my delegate

```
Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 62
    visible:model.vis
    Button{color:model.rectcolor}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still interested in hiding delegates of a GridView without a filter model, the solution is to create a Grid instead, inside a Flickable element. This will even allow your grid to have animations when hiding delegates.

For a live example on Grid, check the Qt QML example *positioners*.

```
ListModel {
    id: model
    ListElement {
        rectcolor:"red"
        vis:true
    }
    ListElement {
        rectcolor:"green"
        vis:false
    }
    ListElement {
        rectcolor:"brown"
        vis:true
    }
}    

Flickable {
    anchors.fill: parent

    contentWidth: width
    contentHeight: grid.height

    clip: true

    Grid {
        id: grid
        width: parent.width
        height: childrenRect.height + 40
        rowSpacing: 10
        columnSpacing: 10

        property int cellSize: 140

        columns: {
            Math.floor(width / 150)
        }

        move: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 200; easing.type: Easing.OutSine }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: model
            delegate: Rectangle {
                color: rectColor
                visible: vis
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone which tries to run the code, add width and height properties to the Repeater delegate. If not it won't be display nothing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to exclude item from `ListView`(or `GridView`, etc) set `visible` and `enable` variables in `delegate` to `false`

Comment: Thanks ! 
I previously was setting `visible` to `false` and  `height` to `0`. But it took seconds to update the view with 5000+ delegates. By setting `enabled` to `false` instead of nulling the `height` it's now instant.

Comment: what do you mean under "set `visible` and `enable` variables in `delegate` ..." ? Delegate can be anything (even `Component` which doesn't have properties except `id`). Could you please clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

you may hide delegate by resizing him to zero (as variant of fast and dirty method)

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: model.vis ? 100 : 0
        height: model.vis ? 62 : 0
        visible:model.vis
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: model.rectcolor
        }
    }
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement {
            rectcolor: "red"
            vis:true
        }
        ListElement {
            rectcolor: "green"
            vis:false
        }
        ListElement {
         rectcolor: "brown"
         vis:true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Resizing the delegates to zero causes a huge lag on a big model, I believe it's the `ListView` recomputing each delegates position (see my comment on @Dcow's answer).
The correct answer is the one given by @Dcow, and it also has the advantage to be simpler.