# Hide an item (delegate) inside a ListView QML

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to hide a particular item on some event in a ListView?

So far I can do it by setting `visible` to `false` and `height` to zero of a delegate.

But If i have spacing in a listView set to 2 for example it appears that this solution is broken.

[image]

Comment: You should either implement spacing as a part of a delegate or use [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html)

Comment: Yes, definitely put spacing inside the delegate, the proxy is overkill IMO.

Comment: It depends on the number of delegates needed to be hidden.

Comment: @folibis stoped on setting `height = 0 - spacing`

Comment: @dtech and no need in storing spacing inside a delegate. ListView already does it.

Comment: @GrecKo like 20 is maximum

Comment: There are many cases where embedding the spacing in the delegate is the solution, for example if you want different delegates to have different spacing. Or if you have some design that is more complex than just a column of boxes. Haven't tried negative height, and its quite interesting if it ends up working as required in this case.

Comment: @dtech yep working as expected. Maybe in the future I will regret it but so far so good.

Comment: A cleaner solution in my opinion would be that the model itself updates and remove the items you don't want to display (not the data from memory, but the elements from the model). It's more work, but in case you display this list in different views it gets much more robust and easy to manage.

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way is to use a proxy model that filters out the elements that should not be displayed.
You can use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) or implement your own [QAbstractProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html).
With that it is even possible to animate the removal and addition of the elements.

Or use [SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel) if you don't wanna touch C++ and performance is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

A hack around this could be to set the spacing of the `ListView` to 0 and implement it in the delegate itself. Something like this:

```
ListView{
   id: listView
   spacing: 0
   delegate: Item{
      id: itemDelegate
      width: parent.width; height: spacingRect.height + actualDelegate.height
      Item {id: actualDelegate;} // your actual delegate
      Rectangle{ id: spacingRect; height: 2; width: parent.width; color: "transparent"; anchors.top: actualDelegate.bottom}
   }
}
```

In this way when you hide the delegate the spacing will also be hidden